# C# Active Directory - Query Unsuccessful Login Attempts

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, userprincipal

Is there a way to return a list of Active Directory login attempts using C#? For example, I would like to somehow return a list that contains the following

- DC Name
- Site
- User State
- Bad Pwd Count
- Last Bad Pwd
- PWD Last Set
- Lockout Time

Essentially, I would like to know which device that is accessing Active Directory is causing a password lockout, on password updates.

I have looked at using the `UserPrincipal` class in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` but I cannot find a method that allows one to aggregate across DCs.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in support for aggregating across multiple DCs. You have to handle that manually. This might get you started - this code will give you all domain controllers. Note - if you run this on a computer outside of the domain, it will throw an exception.

```
foreach (var l_DomainController in Domain.GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(l_DomainController.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought I might have to do things in that manner!